# i have a problem when use select statement in relationship, how can i select images.path column in this statement

Tags: laravel, select, eloquent

```
try {
        $products = $this->productRepo->with(['images'])->select('products.name', 'products.price', 'images.path')->where('category_id', $categoryId)->get();
        dd($products->toArray());
        return response()->json($products, 200);
    } catch (\Throwable $th) {
        $messager = $th->getMessage();
        return response()->json($messager, 404);
    }
```

"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'images.path' in 'field list' (SQL: select `products`.`name`, `products`.`price`, `images`.`path` from `products` where `category_id` = 1 and `products`.`deleted_at` is null)"

[This is code i declare relation ship using l5repository (model Product)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAKsr.jpg) 

[In model Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3AuCi.png)

Comment: what is relationship between product and images? one to many or one to one

Comment: It is one to many. product has many images

Comment: This is the first time i use laravel version 8 so i don't know how to declare relationship when i use l5repository packet. i think it is prolem

Comment: nope, it's because you are using eager load not inner join, check my answer

Comment: thank you, i understand but the result is empty array (images) when i use your code and when my code not using select statement it is also empty array. I think  problem is declare relationship at model. Can you check my images i have upload in prolem.

Comment: show me database structure

Comment: Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->double('price');
            $table->integer('qty'); // quantity of product
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id');
            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
            $table->softDeletes();
            $table->timestamps();
        });

Comment: Schema::create('images', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('path');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('product_id');
            $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products');
            $table->softDeletes();
            $table->timestamps();
        });

Comment: categories(first, before products) Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->softDeletes();
            $table->timestamps();
        });

Comment: i have used l5repository packet but it not support laravel version 8 and my problem is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get some fields from a relationship must implement a query in `with` method:

```php
    try {
        $products = $this->productRepo->with(['images' => function($query) {
            $query->select(['path']);
        }])->select(['name', 'price'])->where('category_id', $categoryId)->get();
        dd($products->toArray());
        return response()->json($products, 200);
    } catch (\Throwable $th) {
        $messager = $th->getMessage();
        return response()->json($messager, 404);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

because `with(['images'])` is eager load so it's getting relationship after retrive data. you can use join to select `images.path` but if you prefer eager load:

```
$products = $this->productRepo->with(['images'])->select('products.name', 'products.price')->where('category_id', $categoryId)->get();

foreach($products as $product) {
   $product->images->pluck("path"); // assume one to many
}
```